# Lucene Query in alfresco for Exact property match only

Tags: lucene, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am using below query to search document.
My first query is=

```
TYPE:"hr:hrdoctype" AND @cm\:name:"E1"
```

and my second query is=

```
TYPE:"hr:hrdoctype" AND @cm\:name:"E2"
```

Here its giving the proper result.

But there is one problem, that if i will use

```
TYPE:"hr:hrdoctype" AND @cm\:name:"E"
```

Then it is displaying both records that is `E1` and `E2`. But I don't have any record with name `E`. So is there any to get exact match?

Here, my requirement is if I search with name `E it` should not have to display any record. The record should display only when exact match occurs.

Can anyone help me with this requirement?

I think it happens because of it is tokenized in `alfresco` for full text search. But my requirement is different.

I am using `alfresco 5.0.d`

Please provide a way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a way to do an 'exact match', take a look [here](http://docs.alfresco.com/community5.0/concepts/rm-searchsyntax-exact.html).

So for example in your case it would look like:

```
TYPE:"hr:hrdoctype" AND =@cm\:name:"E"
```

Be sure to search with FTS so it knows the exact search match.
In javascript it will look like:

```
var query = "TYPE:\"hr:hrdoctype\" AND =@cm\\:name:\"E\";
var def = {
       query: query ,
       language: "fts-alfresco" 
};
var results = search.query(def);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tahir, This is what i was looking for.  Its working fine in my case.